# Ruby on Rails 5.2 - Can Activestorage treat Oracle databases as a service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rails-activestorage

I have been eagerly awaiting the opportunity to upgrade my development environment to Rails version >= 5.2 since I believed the activestorage functionality would finally free me from dependency on a gem for my file uploads and downloads.

Studying the documentation for activestorage has disappointed me. Is it truly exclusive to Cloud storage services and local file attachments? My business need is to store data files in an Oracle database.

I am wondering, since the connection configurations are defined in a .yml file much like the database.yml, can we simply define the database as a service? Something like this:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

oracle:
  service: ORA
  database connection data, etc....
```

Is it possible?

Edit: I sense that I am about to be very embarrassed by my train of thought. The ActiveStorage tables and the attachments would be in the same Oracle database. Of course, I see now, why would ActiveStorage need to have its own database defined as a service? I'm not sure how to even phrase my question now. I guess the question is, can I do this? Can I have the file attachments and the ActiveStorage tables in the same database?

My face is quite red right now, thank you, engineersmnky, for your patience and for taking the time to discuss this with me.

Comment: Are you saying you just want to store the contents of a file e.g. `File.read(#...)` but not the file itself? If so I can't understand why this would be difficult to implement without a gem or `ActiveStorage` honestly 90% of the functionality provided really is in regards to physical storage anyhow.

Comment: I mean, no, I want to store the entire file. I am currently using a gem for file upload/download. The gem does not provide functionality to handle multiple files, so rather than switching to a different gem I was hoping activestorage would meet my needs

Comment: ActiveStorage can support multiple files although so can most of the "upload/download" gems if the data is designed correctly. I am just confused as to what the actual question is here. Are you looking for a separate database connection to an Oracle DB? What problem are you actually facing and why did you think `ActiveStorage` would be able to solve it?

Comment: The way I am reading the documentation seems to indicate that activestorage is exclusively designed to work with two types of storage - the file system, and a cloud based data repository. But not databases. I would like to validate that assumption, and hopefully find a way for activestorage to work with my Oracle database. I hope that clarifies my question? I know sometimes I have to work hard to communicate in this forum.

Comment: ActiveStorage uses 2 database tables (attachments and blobs)  to manage the ORM relationships. The blob table still needs to reference a physical location for the file so that it can retrieve the file as needed by your application. This physical location is what you are referring to as "the file system" and "Cloud". Where do you intend to store the physical files if not locally or elsewhere?

Comment: I already store the physical files in the application database, which is Oracle. That means the 2 ActiveStorage tables that will be created will be in the same database as the file attachments. That is, IF that configuration is plausible. I question whether that is a valid configuration for ActiveStorage.

Comment: It is designed to be in the same database it sounded like you were trying to deviate from that. Just follow the instructions to set it up and you should be good to go